# BadAlloc X Error

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm, gtk2, x11

Im having some problems with a GTK program im trying to build.

When i compile it i keep getting this error:

```
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)'.
(Details: serial 195 error_code 11 request_code 53 minor_code 0)
```

Ive traced it down to the following command that appears to be causing it:

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (Top_Graph), Widget_Get (Graph_Cpu), TRUE, TRUE, 0);
```

Top_Graph and Graph_Cpu are both GtkVbox Widgets.

Has anyone ever seen an error like this, and could they give me some advice as to how it is caused.

Answer (score 1):

This is X server error. These errors are reported asynchronously (some time after the erroneous command was issued). Try running your program with --sync command line option and see what then happens.

Comment: Not informative, that is the debug that gets printed out when the error happens

Comment: Wow, remind me never to post answers to your questions paultop6.  You get voted down for giving a useful answer.

He's right though.  X errors are reported asynchronously, so the line you're claiming to have traced this down to is inaccurate.  There's no way gtk_box_pack_start() can directly generate an X error.  You can run with --sync under gdb, although you're not going to be able to trace the error down to a particular line of code.  But you may be able to trace it down to a particular window and widget, which should help some.

Comment: I apologise for the comment i made, inexperience with x errors and gtk led me to think that the error was directly related to the gtk command.

Comment: I am encountering this error with a ruby-gtk application. I get it when reading quite large local files into a Gtk::TextBuffer widget. I don't think I can use --sync since that does not exist for ruby-gtk3 I think. Xorg seems like a black box to me right now - I have no idea how the error is caused specifically or how one can work around it. It is also not very specific and helpful, just BadAlloc ... :( (it works fine for smaller files by the way, so it must have something to do with some memory or RAM limit or something).